# Using UIAlertController with tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I was using actionsheet in one of the tab in tabbarcontroller. So its working was like this when I click on the tab button it shows me the actionsheet. The code I was using was this

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"someText",nil];
sheet.tag = 1;
[sheet showFromTabBar:application.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Then I use the delegate method to get the button clicked and it was working fine.

Then I decided to change to UIAlertcontroller and the code I am using is this

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *cancelButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        #do something
    }];
UIAlertAction *sButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Send" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        #do something
    }];
[actionSheet addAction:sButton];
[actionSheet addAction:cancelButton];
[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now when I run this code and switch to the tab I am getting an crash saying

> Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target

What am I doing wrong? Can we use UIAlertController with tabbarcontroller?

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self actionSheetInit];#this where actionsheet is called
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: What is `self`?  A view controller on the tab bar?  Can you verify that `actionSheet` is non-nil?

Comment: @JAL yes it is a view controller on the tab bar, how to check actionsheet is non-nil?

Comment: Use the debugger and make sure `actionSheet` is not nil before presenting it.

Comment: @JAL yes when I po actionsheet it shows nil, what to do?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that with the code you provided.  For testing purposes, I put your code in an empty view controller's `viewDidAppear` method.  Where are you calling this code?

Comment: maybe u can try change your `tittle` and `message` to `@""` instead of `nil` and see

Comment: @JAL I am calling it in viewWillAppear

Comment: @user2413621 move your code to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @Tj3n that's not the issue here.  `nil` or the empty string will work, since `title` and `message` are `nullable NSString *`

Comment: @JAL I am still getting the crash after moving to viewDidAppear

Comment: Are you sure the crash is being caused by the alert controller?  Can you post the view controller's full `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @JAL look at the edited code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96112/discussion-between-user2413621-and-jal).